# Carousel not working in laravel 5

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

In my laravel 5 eCommerce web application, I have to make the dynamic carousels. I have made it, but there is 1 issue. Blank space is shown if the carousel does not have the products. How do I make it infinite loop ?

Here's the detail:

Consider I have 8 products in the carousels.

In the first slide (when the user lands on the page), he sees first 6 products out of 8 products. Now when he clicks the right arrow button, the carousel slides and shows the other 2 products (which is fine). But there is also a left over space of 4 products. So, to avoid that space, I have 2 options:

1. **Continue the loop:** After showing product 7 and product 8 in the second slide, it should again show product 1 and start over again.
2. **Stop the carousel at the end:** On second slide, the user should see only the other 2 products. Meaning, the carousel should slide up to 2 more products along with the previous slider's 4 products and should stop.

Now I have opted **Option 1**. But I am failing to make it infinite.

Can anybody help me out in this.

**view**

```
<div class="container">
    <?php $i = $j = $k = 0; ?>
    @foreach($carousels as $key => $carousel)
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <h3>{{ $carousel }}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="controls pull-right hidden-xs">
                    <a class="left fa fa-chevron-left btn btn-success" href="#{{ $carousel }}" data-slide="prev"></a>
                    <a class="right fa fa-chevron-right btn btn-success" href="#{{ $carousel }}" data-slide="next"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div id="{{ $carousel }}" class="carousel slide hidden-xs" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    @foreach($prds as $prd => $products)
                        <div class="item active">
                            @foreach($products as $m => $product)
                                @if( $k < 6 )
                                    @if( $i == $j )
                                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                                            <div class="col-item">
                                                <div class="photo">
                                                    <img src="{{ url('/images/uploads/products/' . Safeurl::make($product->image_code) . '-163-163.jpg') }}" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                                </div>
                                                {{ $product->prod_name }}
                                                <br />
                                                <a href="" class="hidden-sm">Add to Cart</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    @endif
                                @endif
                                <?php $k++; ?>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                        @if($k > 6)
                            @if( $i == $j )
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                                        <div class="col-item">
                                            <div class="photo">
                                                <img src="{{ url('/images/uploads/products/' . Safeurl::make($product->image_code) . '-163-163.jpg') }}" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                            </div>
                                            {{ $product->prod_name }}
                                            <br />
                                            <a href="" class="hidden-sm">Add to Cart</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            @endif
                        @endif
                        <?php $i++; ?>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php $j++; ?>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

I tried this, but didn't helped:

```
$('.carousel .item').each(function() {
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    if (next.next().length>0) {
        next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    } else {
        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

**P.S.**: All the carousel details are coming from the database.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're mixing PHP and Blade syntax? :s